# Why can't object inside a Kotlin companion object be accessed "statically" when other members can?

Tags: kotlin

Given a Kotlin companion object

```
class A {
    companion object {
        val a = 0
        fun b() = 1
        object C {
            val d = 0
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(A.a)
    println(A.b())
    println(A.C.d) // doesn't compile
    println(A.Companion.C.d)
}
```

Why is `Companion` required to access `A.C` when it isn't for `a` and `b()`?

Comment: You can try `@JvmStatic`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This serves the purpose of disambiguating an object declared in a companion object from one declared directly in the class.

Note that the properties and functions defined in a class are not ambiguous with those from the companion object, because the former ones can only be called on an instance of the class. But a nested object can be referenced with the class name:

```
class A {
    object C {
        val d = 0
    }
}

println(A.C.d)
```

Comment: That last was the part I missed (that objects behave like nested classes in this respect).